# imshow do not display image extracted from ndarray. No error

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I need to implement a life game like.
I work with Pyzo and

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) on Windows (64 bits).
This is the Pyzo interpreter with integrated event loop for PYQT5.
```

To do so, I would like the map to be the world map instead of a square.
So I get a monochrome image. I open it, I convert it in array. But I'm unable to display it. There is no error, the log message I set in the code seems to show everything is ok, but the window with the image is not displayed. I also tried with a RGBA image without more success
I also tried after rebooting my PC.

The image is a bmp saved with paint in bitmap monochrome. I joined it
Thanks for any ideas to solve this issue.

Here are the messages from my code

```
format: BMP   mode: 1   palette: None
The image is 993 x 579
ok
[[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 ...
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]
0
(579, 993)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
should be displayed
```

Here is the code

```
def Load_image(filename):
#    try:
    img = Image.open(filename) 
    print ('format: %s   mode: %s   palette: %s' % (img.format,img.mode,img.palette))
    print ('The image is %d x %d' % img.size)
    return img
 #    except:
    print ("Unable to open %s" % filename)
    return -1

def Img2Array(img):
    # BytePerPixel = {'1': 1, 'RGB': 2, 'RGBA' : 4 }# 1: B&W, 3: RGB, 4: RGBA (A=Alpha : transparency)
    # result = numpy.array(img.getdata(), numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], BytePerPixel.get(img.mode))
    result = numpy.array(img,dtype='int8')
    print (result)
    print(result[200,200])
    print(result.shape)
    print (type(result))
    print (type(result[200,200]))

    test = plt.imshow(result)
    print ("should be displayed")
    return result

fichiercarte = "C:\\Users\\mld\\Desktop\\python\\world-map1.bmp"
carte = Load_image(fichiercarte)
if (carte != None): 
   print ("ok")
ndArrayCarteDuMonde = Img2Array (carte)
```

[Monochrome world map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH7Ab.png)

Comment: Insert `plt.show()` after `test = plt.imshow(result)`. `imshow` does not actually show the canvas, as the name would imply.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much MPA ! The map is now displayed. But instead of being black and white, it is purple and yellow. Why the palette changed ? And how to fix that ?  Besides the documentation of imshow(result) https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html, says Display an image, i.e. data on a 2D regular raster. and plt.show() says Display a figure. It's confusing.

Comment: By default, `imshow` uses the viridis colourmap. You can pick a colourmap of your choosing [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and select it using `plt.imshow(data, cmap="your_cmap")`. To get blacks and whites, use `plt.imshow(data, cmap="binary")`.